# Особенности работы буфера в потоках

Tags: c

Допустим у меня поток связан с файлом и стоит буферизация. Функцией fwrite я пишу в буфер, при заполнении он сбрасывается на диск. А как с fread? Он тоже считывает в буфер? Если да, то зачем?

Comment: Если вы работаете с одним файловым дескриптором - то буфер общий и проблем не будет. Если нет - то надо задействовать ф-ции синхронизации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, fread также использует буфер для ускорения чтения. Почему? да просто в большинстве случаев с старых hdd дисков что 1 байт прочитать, что сотню, разницы почти нет. Но только если читать побайтно, то скорость упадет ниже плинтуса.

Современные операционные системы могут считывать весь файл в память в параллель и в этом случае чтение будет очень быстрым.

Comment: То есть если я захочу считать fread-ом например 100 байтов файла, у меня буфер полностью заполнится и в буфере будут лежать мои запрошенные 100 байтов и BUFFERSIZE-100 байтов, следующих за этими 100 байтами в памяти?

Comment: возможно. А может и весь файл будет считан. Но для Вас это будет абсолютно прозрачно.